# openssl certificate verification in RedHat Linux 8 fails

Tags: linux, openssl

For the same cacert.pem openssl returns different results.

certificate verification fails in Redhat linux 8 but successfully verifies in Redhat linux 7.5

```
[rhel8]: openssl verify cacert.pem
C = NO, L = Asker, O = E1, OU = ETO TER, CN = ETO Opto Certificate Authority
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
error cacert.pem: verification failed
```

RHEL 7.5:

```
[rhel7.5]: openssl verify cacert.pem
ca-certs.pem: C = NO, L = Asker, O = E1, OU = ETO TER, CN = ETO Opto Certificate Authority
error 18 at 0 depth lookup:self signed certificate
OK
```

Comment: Please add openssl versions and command lines `openssl verify ...`.

Comment: [rhl7.5]: openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017

[rhel8]:openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1 FIPS  11 Sep 2018

Answer (score 0):

In your case (a self signed cetificate), the 2 versions of openssl do not return the same code.

- OpenSSL 1.0.2 returns 0
- OpenSSL 1.1.1 returns 2

This is documented in the changelog:

> Changes between 1.0.2h and 1.1.0  [25 Aug 2016]
>
> [...]
>
> *) Make openssl verify return errors.

Your version 1.0.2k is on the branch 1.0.2, and behaves as in 1.0.2h.